# Wordpress, AJAX and pre_get_posts using conditional tags

Tags: php, wp-query, ajax, conditional-tags

I have a page that returns a list of posts in a custom post type. This is generated by a third party plugin. I want to omit the posts that are using a custom post status 'template'. Really the only posts I want to show here are post with the post status 'publish'.

My original code is:

```
// Hide Master_Templates on Inventory Page
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_templates_query' );

    function hide_templates_query( $query ) {
        if ((is_page ('inventory')) {   
            $query->set( 'post_status' , 'publish' );
            return $query;
        }
    }
```

On page load this works fine but there are filters on the page that use AJAX to sort and filter the posts. If you set any of those it overrides my query variable. From research it seems that AJAX does not pass the page its sent from, thus the query argument is ignored.

If I use this:

```
// Hide Master_Templates on Inventory Page
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_templates_query' );

    function hide_templates_query( $query ) {
        if ((is_page ('inventory') || ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX )) ) {    
            $query->set( 'post_status' , 'publish' );
            return $query;
        }
    }
```

It works great, but this causes problems on other pages. Is there a way to define just the AJAX calls on that specific page?

Comment: Is the some unique data sent with these requests that you can check for the presence of?

Comment: Don't know much about AJAX but the only unique thing I see is the action itself, filter_listing. If I could use that I would work I think.